# PHP echo function to echo something blank

Tags: php, echo

I am not the best when it comes to PHP, but I am doing a canonical tag, and want each page URL to be different.

When I input:

```
<?php echo $page->url; ?>
```

It works on pages that have been added via the CMS system with an ID, but not on pages such as account area which are built in.

How do I simply have it so it shows a page URL, unless it is not on a page with an ID, so it instead echos nothing (empty space)?

$page->id - for reference

Any advice appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the property is set before

`<?php echo isset($page->url) ? $page->url : ''; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). If `$page->id` **isn't** `empty`, echo it otherwise echo  `$page->url`, i.e.:

```
<?php echo !empty($page->id) ? $page->id  : $page->url; ?>
```